# Python win32com with R reticulate

Tags: python, r, win32com, reticulate

When I use the Python lib `win32com` directly in Python like:

```
import win32com.client
```

everything works fine.

However, I need to use the lib with `reticulate` in an R script like:

```
library(reticulate)
reticulate::use_python('C:/python3/python.exe')

# Load basic Python lib or "site-package" located in the python directory C:/python3/lib/site-packages/PACKAGE
os = reticulate::import("os") 

# Load win32 from some other directory
w32 = reticulate::import_from_path("win32com.client", path = "C:/mypath_to_libs/")
```

But I get the error:

> No module named 'win32api'

I suppose this has to do with some `*.dll` files required by `win32com`. These are found when I use `win32com` directly in Python but seem to be "missing" when I use `win32com` in R through `reticulate`.

I tried to copy the `*.dll` files to the main Python PATH and also added a (temporary) PATH (pointing to the directory containing the `*.dll`), but this did not help.

I'm using Python 3.9.11 (64bit) on a Windows PC (as shown by `reticulate::py_config()`). The R version is 4.1.3 (64bit). Do I need to use a 32bit version of Python here?

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: I tried running it with only `w32 = reticulate::import_from_path("win32com.client")` and it works fine in my end.

Comment: Thx for having a look at this, but I need to give a path since the lib is located in another directory than the Python installation. I cannot change this, I‘m afraid. I guess this is part of the problem (since the DLL are not found, I suspect).